# How to keep smallest non-zero value(s) in each row of a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a symmetric matrix with `0`'s on the diagonal:

```
[[0.   4.   1.25 1.25]
 [4.   0.   9.25 1.25]
 [1.25 9.25 0.   4.  ]
 [1.25 1.25 4.   0.  ]]
```

I want to keep the smallest `k` non-zero distinct values in each row and zero the rest. For example, if `k = 1`, I would have:

```
[[0.   0.   1.25 1.25]
 [0.   0.   0.   1.25]
 [1.25 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [1.25 1.25 0.   0.  ]]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
k = 1
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    ind = np.argsort(matrix[i,:])
    matrix[i, ind[k + 1:]] = 0
```

Out:

```
[[0.   0.   1.25 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   1.25]
 [1.25 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   1.25 0.   0.  ]]
```

I can take the set of values in each row and then zero the value if it doesn't belong in the set, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Edit: For `k = 2`, the desired result is:

```
[[0.   4.   1.25 1.25]
 [4.   0.   0.   1.25]
 [1.25 0.   0.   4.  ]
 [1.25 1.25 4.   0.  ]]
```

and for `k = 3`:

```
[[0.   4.   1.25 1.25]
 [4.   0.   9.25 1.25]
 [1.25 9.25 0.   4.  ]
 [1.25 1.25 4.   0.  ]]
```

Comment: Desired results for k=2 or k=3??

Comment: @wwii Keep the smallest 2/3 non-zero distinct values..

Answer (score 0):

> symmetric matrix with 0's on the diagonal

For k=1: Fill the diagonal with a large value; then use np.where with row minimums being the condition.

```
a = [[0.  , 4.  , 1.25, 1.25],
     [4.  , 0.  , 9.25, 1.25],
     [1.25, 9.25, 0.  , 4.  ],
     [1.25, 1.25, 4.  , 0.  ]]
a = np.array(a)

np.fill_diagonal(a,a.max()+1)
cond = a == a.min(-1)
b = np.where(cond,a,0)
```

That matches your desired result for k=1 but your text description seems to say that you only want to keep `k` values in each row.

---

This works for any k ...
Sticking with a for loop for now: find the unique nonzero values in each row; use the first `k` of those values to make a mask; use the mask to fill *non-conforming* items with zero.

```
def f(a,k=1):
    for row in a:
        values = row[row.nonzero()]
        values = np.unique(values)    #returns a sorted array
        values = values[:k]
        mask = (row[:,None] != values).all(1)
        row[mask] = 0
    return a

q = f(a,k=2)
```

Maybe not the best solution since you find the use of np.unique inelegant.

---